# Can "mata itsuka" be used in casual conversation?

Tags: usage, phrases, greetings, casual

Recently I came across this exchange:

Person A: Ja ne.

Person B: Mata aou.

Person C: Ja ne. Mata itsuka.

Real casual till that last line. I've been told that "itsuka" is a way to express uncertainty.

1. Does this make the exchange bittersweet, despite the casual tone of both speakers?

2. Can 'mata itsuka' be used in casual Japanese?

3. Does it infer that the speakers will or will not meet again?

Thanks in advance~!

Answer (score 5):

Whether the exchange is bittersweet or not will depend on them and their relationship.

But yes, it is usable, although I never really had the chance to hear it myself. It does show a rather high level of uncertainty. It can be used when you don't know if you will ever meet again, or if the next time you meet is simply not decided yet and might not be soon.

またいつか (used after high school reunions and such.)

> If the opportunity ever arises, let's meet again.

また今度 (used for people you meet on a daily/weekly basis)

> See you next time!

Comment: I haven't heard またいつか to mean a near time before. Oftentimes I hear また今度 or また明日 for example, when the time is known (such as tomorrow), or nearby. Think of the expression in English "See you sometime" -- I think it's a little dependent on tone as well?

Comment: >またいつか (used after high school reunions and such.)   A good example!